# python machine-learning variable length string qualifier

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am trying to incorporate a variable length string into python machine-learning data.  The string consists of 21 possible uppercase characters in lengths from 3 to more than 1000, but generally from 50 to 500 characters long. I was wanting to add this data to existing machine learning systems because this string is what the rest of the numerical data in the system is derived.  I am hoping that by incorporating this information into the system, the accuracy of the predictions can be increased.

Machine-learning systems used: SVR from scikit-learn, gradient boosted random forest from xgboost, neural network using a combination of Theano and Keras.

Example data (spaces added for clarity, one of thousands of sets):
*0.20783132530120485, 0.0, 0.14759036144578314, 0.0, 20.500779795353044, -0.012854043345111421, 20.856396736982024, -0.019526697858776032, 0.17055840352519377*, **MLKQLLTVVLLAICLINVQAQQLTPPAGTFRLGISKGTDSHWLAPQEKVKGIAFRWKALPDTRGFILEVAVTSLQQADTLFWSFGNCQPDMDINVFSVEGQAFTCYYGESMKLRTLQAVTPTDDIRLSNGRQDKTPLLLYESGKRTDRPVLAGRCPLAANSKLYFCFYEQNARADYNYFMLPDLFAKIDESKHSKK**, 3907.222610216657, 0.0, 12.957234316695068, 260.35949614307845, 70.22897891511785, 0.0, 3600.1557026363694, 6.5695226674325005, 8.875805301569174E-9, 9.435201047407471E-8, -805.7695207777524, -0.386030775564303, 2.4360867449746193E-4, 0.001535275768898734, -899.103861896121, 0.37012002714844283, 41.30865237441297, 0.6880193813262029, 0.07901855928913903, 0.36786993202927, 0.027022889508663273, 0.20983595671723698, 0.004272043781893587, 2.6548618772402452, 0.8298948072745838, 0.4297709789614357, 0.6592421241850477, 0.7323455585665695, 0.0036084082526088635, 1235.9608595043105, -686.3410939120973, 517.5695296420419, 0.0, 1383.9587599495007, 137.6709125154875, 48.15897140522527, 11.169320592630035, 0.0017212126730760488, 390.0, 576.0, 162.0, 425.0, -2337.586240324919, -1216.645095553551, -220.7658611143325, -254.87026759361316, -120.44151020211892, -262.1549293391522, -262.70857652215483, -119.78950303227985, -14.056523664351944, -16.03338970562135, -15.397779250982714, -4.190420980506957, -52.306453723320466, -17.804935707496412, -1602.015046949609, -695.3200007491427, -282.2011792651323, -624.4938669353348, 319.12737432671895, -91.65456051126749, 190.69831510254096, 220.08361973544459, 2971.554863316476, 262.57174547648316, 2708.983117839995, 0.0, 5.482741129097017, -132.68200592716775, -4341.712499207881, 9.524948063475861, 4.203276705216416, -4.307639899059003, 3.1644632985485313, 2.81419659034428, 2.963504627059134, 3.4913480163824713, 0.0031707417031467916, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0015698345827278798, 0.0016205522602160554, -1.9645139797143648E5, 0.9504047512545211, 0.9833528676885283, 0.9597468652322548, 0.9865496952192033, 0.9175964036143727, 16312.662271951838, 15062.220268073073, 1250.4420038787648, 0.0, 2.7244897959183674, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10.306122448979592, 0.0, 29.26530612244898, 0.0, 7.797822706065319, 0.0, 228.06859068818272, 0.4027714206386829, 1652.1493757294986, 3410.905281836304, 0.5612244897959183, 0.844845002268259, 0.5834395722203105, 1.0, 1.0, 1797.0, 362.119, 196.0, 1.0, -307.795, 0.000, -847.358, 202.875, -73.825, 2.064, 79.019, 452.437, -10.090, -45.351, -9.292, -36.652, 10.749, -38.050, 23.004, -18.505, 0.837, 0.344

[the first 9 fields (in italics) are derivative data, evaluating the rest of the numerical data (possible "Y's"), the next field (in bold) is the string data that needs to be incorporated, the rest is the main input to the machine-learning ("X")]

Comment: you'll need to find a way to ensuring the information the learner gets is fixed-length. i.e. featurization of the information (bag-of-words, k-means, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to think about what information does that string provide? Can this somehow be quantizied with a number?

If you cant read information out of the string, why should the machine be able to do so?